# Не могу преобразовать данные из JSON

Tags: swift, swift3

Всем привет.
Я подключась к базе и получаю оттуда данные вот таким образом:

```
   let myJson = try?JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers ) as! NSArray
```

Получаю ответ:

```
print(myJson!)
```

Вывожу в консоль:

```
(
        {
        0 = 4;
        1 = nnbnvb;
        2 = 0554097907;
        3 = "";
        4 = 12332198566;
        carnumber = "";
        id = 4;
        name = nnbnvb;
        number = 0554097907;
        password = 12332198566;
    }
)
```

Как эти элементы записать в переменные?
Буду благодарен спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть пустой проект к примеру
и мы хотим залогиниться, что бы нам залогиниться нам нужно отправить POST запрос на определенную ссылку и получить в ответ JSONe ответ который мы будем парсить
и какие то данные мы поместим в словарь так как будем их использовать в дальнейшем и что бы каждый раз эти данные не запрашивать мы поместим их в словарь (Dictionary) это такая штука которая хранит небольшие данные в памяти телефона и так приступим

//Создаем пустой контейнер user в файле AppDelegate

```
var user : NSDictionary?
```

в ViewControllere мы будем описывать логику

шаг первый прикрепим к vc в mainstoryboard 2 TextField и прикрепим их к VC а так же прикрепим  UIButton это будет кнопка входа

в итоге у нас в VC должно получиться следующие

```
@IBOutlet var loginTxt: UITextField! // Это поле для логина
@IBOutlet var passwordTxt: UITextField! // Это поле для пароля
@IBAction func loginBtn(_ sender: Any) {  // а это кнопка

}
```

только не помести кнопку в `override func viewDidLoad()` так как эта функция отвечает немного за другое про нее погугли подробнее...

и так в class нам необходимо добавить делегат UITextFieldDelegate он отвечает за делегирование данных по названию понятно это доступ в файл appDelegate `var user : NSDictionary?`

шаг второй когда мы все прикрепили можем начать кодить логику

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

class LoginVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // UI
    @IBOutlet var loginTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTxt: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    @IBAction func loginBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        //Если текста нет то вернем ошику и подсветим красным шрифтом что не было введено
        if loginTxt.text!.isEmpty || passwordTxt.text!.isEmpty{

            //red colors
            loginTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "login", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

            passwordTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

            // если же все ок делаем запрос
        } else {

            // удаляем кавиатуру
            self.view.endEditing(true)

            // тут мы пихаем в константу login то что было введено в форме и все маленькими буквами
            let login = loginTxt.text!.lowercased()

            // тут по аналогии с пароем
            let password = passwordTxt.text!



            // cоздаем юрлу для запроса .. она будет состоять из 2х частей

            //Это первая
            let myUrl = URL(string: "http://site.ru/api_checkauth");

            var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            // Это вторая

            // это как она выглядит полностью
            //"http://site.ru/api_checkauth?login=\(login)&password=\(password)"


            // в login и password мы передаем те данные из UITextField
            let postString = "login=\(login)&password=\(password)";


            // теперь создаем тело запроса
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


            //так как у нас запрос POST мы юзаем эту конструкцию URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response,

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

                //тут мы делаем проверку на пустоту типо есть ли инет и возвращается ли нам ответ, да весь ответ сейчас лежит в data

                guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }


                // Теперь приступаем к JSON и начинаем играться с преобразованием(as? NSDictionary) это какого типа будут приходить данные
                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                    //помещаем в parseJSON весь ответ от сервера и возвращаем
                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    //Мой jsone если статус success

//     {
//      fullname = "\U0425\U0430\U0447\U0430\U043c\U0443\U0440\U0430\U0434\U043e\U0432 \U0425.";
//      "ibox_login" = "test@ya.ru";
//      "ibox_password" = 123456;
//      id = 86;
//      message = "\U0412\U044b \U0443\U0441\U043f\U0435\U0448\U043d\U043e \U0430\U0432\U0442\U043e\U0440\U0435\U0437\U0438\U0440\U043e\U0432\U0430\U043b\U0438\U0441\U044c, \U0434\U043e\U0431\U0440\U043e \U043f\U043e\U0436\U0430\U043b\U043e\U0432\U0430\U0442\U044c!";
//      status = 200;
//      username = test;
//      }



                    // И вот тут начинается твой парс JSON

                    // parsseJSON["id"] as? String вернет мне id = 86
                    let id = parseJSON["id"] as? String

                    // тут еще одна проверка если id не пусто то идем дальше
                    if id != nil {

                        //Теперь начинаются словари 

                        // тут я кладу весь полученный ответ который выше в ключ parseJSON и заворачиваю в контейнер который мы создали вначале user в appDelegate теперь самое интересное я могу в любом VC получить данные user а в нем у меня лежит весь ответ JSON и я могу обращаться по ключам к любому объекту внутри него

                        UserDefaults.standard.set(parseJSON, forKey: "parseJSON")

                        user = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "parseJSON") as? NSDictionary

                        // не большая проверка залогинен ли юзер
                        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
                            appDelegate.login()
                        })

                    } else {


                        // а тут мы получаем ошибки
                        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
//                            let message = parseJSON["message"] as! String
//                            appDelegate.infoView(message: message,color: colorSmoothRed)

                            // Debug
                            print("Message from json=\(message)")
                        })

                    }


                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        // Теперь я имею доступ к username
                        let username = parseJSON["username"] as? String
                        print("username: \(String(describing: username))")

                        //и к status
                        let statusjson = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                        print("status: \(String(describing: statusjson))")

                    }

                } catch {

                    print(error)
                }
            }


            task.resume() // выход
        }

    }// end button

}
```

ну не знаю как смог ... :)

Comment: Шикарно Просто !Молодец!тебеб статьи писать!

Comment: и вот еще для понимания методов  загрузки

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Укажите последовательность перевода данных из json-структуры в ваши переменные:

```
let car = jsonObject! as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
let carVal0 = car[0] as Number
let carVal1 = car[1] as String
let carVal2 = car[2] as Number
let carVal3 = car[3] as String
let carVal4 = car[4] as Number
let carNumber = car["carnumber"] as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
...
```

Comment: что это ...??? не могли бы расписать .?

Comment: Я не понел вас  можете что-то по яснее дать.

Comment: Я понед вы имеете ввиду каким образом я пытался сделать .;.

Comment: print(myJson!.value(forKey: "carnumber") as? String)

Comment: В какие переменные вы хотите их охранить?

Comment: Да в любые просто создайте переменные сохраните их там выведите в консоль я дальше уже сам пойму.потому что я их немогу вытащить.уже устал прошу.

Comment: Я привёл вам пример сохранения в переменные из массива JSON. Подставьте вместо jsonObject! ваш объект myJson! и сохраните его значения по очереди в переменные.

Comment: Vladimir я сделал не срабгтало жеее

Comment: Он предлагает вам хранить в словаре ... не более того ...

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let str = "{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"],\"status\":[\"200\"],\"message\":\"User has been  created\"}"

let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]


    let status = json["status"] as? [String]

    let name = json["names"]as? [String]

    name?[0]
    name?[1]
    name?[2]


} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Поместите пример в playground и разберитесь
и поучите приведение типов

Comment: Спасисибо!Очень позновельно !

Comment: Еще вы можете проходиться циклом и писать данные скажем в словарь, или в пустую переменную или coredata

Comment: Яб был рад увидеть на примере если есть возможность

Answer (score 1):

```
// Вот вот появится что то делаем
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    // появление View
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    // у view сейчас изменятся фреймы
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }

    // Фреймы изменились
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    // У мобилы кончилась память надо бы почистить
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```